# Dealing with SciPy fmin_bfgs precision loss

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I'm currently trying to solve numerically a minimization problem and I tried to use the optimization library available in SciPy.

My function and derivative are a bit too complicated to be presented here, but they are based on the following functions, the minimization of which do not work either:

```
def func(x):
    return np.log(1 + np.abs(x))
def grad(x):
    return np.sign(x) / (1.0 + np.abs(x))
```

When calling the fmin_bfgs function (and initializing the descent method to x=10), I get the following message:

```
Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
     Current function value: 2.397895
     Iterations: 0
     Function evaluations: 24
     Gradient evaluations: 22
```

and the output is equal to 10 (i.e. initial point). I suppose that this error may be caused by two problems:

- The objective function is not convex: however I checked with other non-convex functions and the method gave me the right result.
- The objective function is "very flat" when far from the minimum because of the log.

Are my suppositions true? Or does the problem come from anything else? 
Whatever the error can be, what can I do to correct this? In particular, is there any other available minimization method that I could use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could replace `np.abs(x)` with a differentiable approximation such as those discussed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728094/approximate-x-with-a-smooth-function). For example, the optimization has no problem when `func` returns  `np.log(1 + np.sqrt(x**2 + 10**-10))`

Comment: Indeed! Thank you for this advise! I did some verification and it seems that the error comes from the non-derivability of the absolute value at 0.

Answer (score 1):

`abs(x)` is always somewhat dangerous as it is non-differentiable. Most solvers expect problems to be smooth. Note that we can drop the `log` from your objective function and then drop the `1`, so we are left with minimizing `abs(x)`. Often this can be done better by the following.

Instead of `min abs(x)` use

```
min t
-t <= x <= t
```

Of course this requires a solver that can solve (linearly) constrained NLPs.

Comment: I know, unfortunately I have no other choice but dealing with absolute values. Besides, I cannot apply your simplification to my actual objective function. The function I gave in my question was just an example to make my problem reproducible without providing the actual function.